# Why is there a vertical gap within my UIScrollView when its member UIView's y = 0?

Tags: uiscrollview, autolayout

Scenario:

1. Add member UIViews into a UIScrollView.
2. Contain member UIViews within a horizontal Stack View (embedded in the UIScrollView), to be scrolled
   horizontally.

I've added my first UIView to be position at y = 0 within the UIScrollView.  However I noticed a gap as shown in image below.   I would have to set a negative y value to position the member UIView upwards to close the gap.

Question: What's causing this gap at y = 0... a margin of some kind? 
How do I make close this gap at y = 0?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this gap also show at runtime?  Sometimes the views render differently in IB than at runtime, especially when they're under a navigation bar.  Also, the view is at position y = 0 with respect to its parent, the scroll view, but where is the scroll view positioned in the stack view?